# Return and parse results from mysql_fetch_assoc

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having trouble getting values out of my array returned from a MySQL query.

The results that are being returned are a table with these columns:

```
|team_id|name|pos|available|
```

There are multiple rows in the result. I need to go through each row and extract `name` and `pos` into their respective variables.

Here is my code:

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM `player_user` WHERE team_id = '$teamID[0]'");
    $answer = mysql_query($query);
    if ($answer === FALSE)
        die(mysql_error());

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($answer)) 
    {
        $pname = $row['name'];
        $pos = $row['pos'];


     ... do something with $pname and $pos 
    }
```

Comment: Don't use the mysql_ functions any more. They are deprecated. Also, your code has a flaw that can allow SQL injection. And don't use `SELECT *` in production code. Just wanted to say all that before people downvote you.

Comment: Just a note, `mysql_query` is deprecated, as is `mysql_fetch_assoc`. You should consider using something else like `MySQLi` or `PDO_MySQL` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

Comment: Also, what is the actual problem? Are `$pname` and `$pos` blank? Are you getting a MySQL error?

Comment: First thought the $teamID[0] is the problem but it is not. The code should work. What happens if you add `var_dump($row);` inside the while loop?

Comment: It seems that an empty result set returns. Execute your query with mysql or whatever IDE you use to check it actually returns data with that `team_id` value. Also show `var_dump($row)` as hek2mgl suggested.

Comment: @siride thanks for the info about mysql_ functions. I'm a beginner and so I'm not very familiar with SQL injection vulnerabilities, or about using the SELECT *. It seems that $pname and $pos are blank...

Comment: I've been using $teamID[0] because when I use this code: 

    $query = sprintf("SELECT team_id FROM `team_user` WHERE user_id = '$user'");
 $answer = mysql_query($query);
 if ($answer === FALSE)
        die(mysql_error());
 $teamID = mysql_fetch_array($answer);    

I can't access the value of the $teamID variable without using $teamID[0]. This returns the team_id of the current user.

Comment: Put `echo($query);` before `$answer = ...` and show us please. Also you did't show `var_dump($row);`

Comment: var_dump($row); did not output anything. This is what $query echoed: SELECT * FROM `player_user` WHERE team_id = '1'. I'm also getting these notices:

Notice: Undefined index: name in D:\xampp\htdocs\debug.php on line 37

Notice: Undefined index: pos in D:\xampp\htdocs\debug.php on line 38

Comment: If var_dump($row); did not output anything then it means that you get an empty result set from DB. Can you execute your sql statement `SELECT * FROM player_user WHERE team_id = '1'` using mysql or whatever tool (phpAdmin, Sequel Pro...) do you use and tell us what you get.

Comment: I get 4 rows with the columns `team_id | name | pos | available` for example ` 1 | Matt Kemp | OF | 0 ` .

Comment: Is it empty? Then check your data in the db. Apparently you don't have any rows in `player_user` table that have `team_id = 1`

Comment: @user1956847 Well, good for you. Please, consider [up vote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17364/how-do-comment-voting-and-flagging-work) comments that helped you to sort that out.

Answer (score 0):

The example above should work, as long as the mysql query will return data. You should verify this using `var_dump($row);` inside the loop.

Although you should use the mysqli extension or PDO to access mysql databases. mysql_* functions as you currently use are deprecated and will once being dropped from PHP

Answer (score -1):

You should use mysqli_fetch_array instead of mysql_fetch_assoc. That should return the results as you want.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Comment: While mysqli is a great idea, there's nothing broken about mysql_ with respect to actually loading a simple row of data.

Comment: If you want the PHP software to be compatible with the future versions then mysqli is a better option. And MYSQLI has the object oriented interface while MYSQL function does not. Even though there are still programs that are being written with non OOP programs, best practice would be to use the newer stuff and learn the new technologies.

Comment: I don't disagree about mysqli, but the problem is not with mysql vs. mysqli, but rather with something else.