# mysql_fetch_assoc - not displaying results

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I'm trying to retrieve my results from my database using mysql_fetch_assoc(), however I do not appear to be getting any results when I echo the following (plain white screen):

```
$email_address = $_POST['email_address'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if(login($email_address, $password)){
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `email_address` = '$email_address' AND `password` = '$password'");
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
        echo $row['email_address'];
    }else{
        echo "Invalid login";
    }
```

Comment: Your query could be failing, or you could be returning 0 rows. You need to verify that `$query` succeeded, and that you are returning rows. Also, you are open to SQL Injection, and you should not be storing passwords as plain text.

Comment: Where is it throwing an error?

Comment: Are you sure that the passwords aren't hashed?

Comment: Add `echo mysql_error();` and `echo mysql_num_rows($query);` before the `$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);` line

Comment: I recommend you take a look at the query used in the `login` function, and model your query after that.

Comment: [Similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14330744/return-and-parse-results-from-mysql-fetch-assoc?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like the following,

```
if (isset($_POST['email_address']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {

$email_address = $_POST['email_address'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

//conection:
$con= mysqli_connect("hostname","username","password","database") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));

//query:
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE users.email_address = '$email_address' AND users.password = '$password'");

//display information:
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

if($email_address == $row['email_address'] && $password == $row['Password']){
echo $row['email_address'];
}else{
echo "Invalid login";
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `if($query==NULL) {/* handle error */}` to catch connection/db errors.

Then

```
$nrows=mysql_num_rows($query); //get the number of rows returned
if($nrows==0) //no match
else if($nrows==1) //match
else {/*more than 1 rows, probably sql injection */}
```

That said, move away from the deprecated MySQL extension and use [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead. Also [hash your passwords](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/36833/why-should-i-hash-passwords) if you intend to get the site public at any point in time, preferably with [bcrypt](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4781/do-any-security-experts-recommend-bcrypt-for-password-storage/6415#64150). See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3rmCGsCYJF8&feature=youtu.be&t=26m28s) for a brief overview on why simple hash functions (even salted) shouldn't be used to hash passwords and why use a [KDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function) instead.

Finally your code is open to SQL injection. [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) on how to secure against it.

As a sidenote, some people avoid doing `SELECT *` because

- The schema might change at a later point in time
- It gives you columns you might not need, therefore extra transfer / processing time
- Selecting the columns you want adds to code clarity

Answer (score 0):

change your query to this, add `die(mysql_error())` to check if there is any error in your query:

```
$email_address = $_POST['email_address'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if(login($email_address, $password)){
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `email_address` = '$email_address' AND `password` = '$password'") or die(mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    echo $row['email_address'];
} else {
    echo "Invalid login";
}
```